# How to send Jersey multipart but with a different content type for each file

Tags: java, jersey

I'm unsure whether you can set the body parts with differing Content-Type headers during a multipart request. I have tried building the entire request out of strings but the endpoint wont accept base64 strings, giving 413request too large.The API docs for the endpoint I'm using seem to require this structure. Currently I have this below but it's throwing errors about mixing the `.field` between the BodyParts.

```
                    addressString += "\r\n\r\n"
                            + "Content-ID: proofOfAddress\r\n"
                            + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                            + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
                            + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=" + addressProofName + "\r\n";

                    idString += "Content-ID: proofOfIdentityDocument\r\n"
                            + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                            + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
                            + "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=" + idProofName + "\r\n";

                     multipartEntity = new FormDataMultiPart()
                        .field("payload", body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                        .field("address", addressString, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .bodyPart((FileDataBodyPart)files.get(0))
                        .field("id", idString, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .bodyPart((FileDataBodyPart)files.get(0))
                        .type(Boundary.addBoundary(new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", Collections.singletonMap(Boundary.BOUNDARY_PARAMETER, "--XXX--"))));
```

Can anyone tell me whether there's another way attach content types to body parts, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression that the content headers for jersey had to be entered individually and file parts added afterwards, but in fact, add a file part adds the headers anyway. So just a misunderstanding, solved with properly perusal of docs.